# Poloniex Api Trouble

Tags: python, bots, urllib, algorithmic-trading, poloniex

So I'm accessing the poloniex API with python and this is my code:

```
from poloniex import Poloniex
import krakenex
import threading
import pprint
import urllib.request
import json
####POLONIEX####

#FUNCTIONS

polo = Poloniex()

def BTC_USDT_LAST_POLONIEX():
  polo = Poloniex()
  threading.Timer(1.0, BTC_USDT_LAST_POLONIEX).start() # called every minute
  print("BTC Last Price = " + (polo('returnTicker')['USDT_BTC']['last']))

def POLONIEX_ASSET_LIST():
    pprint.pprint(sorted(list(polo('returnTicker'))))
```

Everything is working so far and I want to avoid using urllib as its a pain to turn a http request into a list. I'm trying to access the order book but get the following error:

```
>>> polo('returnOrderBook')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    polo('returnOrderBook')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/poloniex/retry.py", line 15, in wrapped
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/poloniex/__init__.py", line 183, in __call__
    return self.parseJson(ret.text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/poloniex/__init__.py", line 197, in parseJson
    raise PoloniexError(jsonout['error'])
poloniex.PoloniexError: Please specify a currency pair.
```

I've tried specifying the currency pair but have no idea how to plug it in.

Comment: I have no idea about your `Poloniex`class. But, you can use `urllib.request` and everything will be fine. I've create a [wrapper for Poloniex](https://github.com/Chiheb-Nexus/PoloniexWrapper/blob/master/PoloniexApi.py), if you want take a look on it.

Comment: Thanks @Chibeb Nexus, you're wrapped is amazing. One quick question. I'm trying to returnOrderBook but I can't enter the currency pair properly. I've tried entering req = {'BTC_ZEC'} for example as an argument but it says TypeError: string indices must be integers. How do I enter it correctly?

Comment: Don't worry I got it, didn't realize the functions below the api_query function were actually using the api_query function to get the data. Thanks for the awesome wrapper!

Comment: thanks. Glade that my comment is helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code and use `requests` module instead of `urllib`:

```
import requests
ret = requests.get('http://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=BTC_BCN').json()
print ret

>>> {u'bids': [[u'0.00000034', 20629605.566027], [u'0.00000033', 43382683.465305], [u'0.00000032', 70007976.087993], [u'0.00000031', 49571221.248027], [u'0.00000030', 77520227.415484], [u'0.00000029', 46037827.046996], [u'0.00000028', 26267440.401662], [u'0.00000027', 22511987.85933], [u'0.00000026', 18885378.040015], [u'0.00000025', 13313109.292994], [u'0.00000024', 6243527.5236432], [u'0.00000023', 7504850.7832509], [u'0.00000022', 8443683.7997507], [u'0.00000021', 8996262.9826951], [u'0.00000020', 24601532.006268], [u'0.00000019', 26853346.478659], [u'0.00000018', 6027262.24889 etc....
```